# Resize svg chart on mobile with D3.js

Tags: css, d3.js, svg

I have a svg chart which looks good on desktop and also if I resize the browser window but it looks way too small on mobile devices (sse screenshots).  What can I do to enlarge the chart on mobile?
[image: chart on desktop][image: chart on mobile]

Here is the online version of the chart:

http://labs.tageswoche.ch/sport/interaktives/transfer_1617/

Right now the width and height are set like this:

```
width = window.innerWidth < 960 ? window.innerWidth - 20 : 920
height = 600
```

And then set on the chart

```
$(function() {
location.hash = ""
svg = d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .append("g")
    // .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

d3.csv("zugaenge.csv", function(err, data) {
    if (err) throw err
    state.data = data
    draw()
})
```

I would like that the chart looks like this in the end:

[image: desired look on mobile]

Comment: just use viewbox and prompt the user to view it in landscape ?

Comment: i don't understand how to use viewbox to get the desired result. I want the chart to look like screenshot 3 on mobile.

Comment: ok, you dont even need view box, just use window.innerWidth and window.innerHeight to get the dimensions of the device and set the width and height vars and you're done. Just a point though, you want it on device, you have no mouseover state on devices so I recommend changing the way you filter the data, i.e when you click. I would change the click event to double click and mouseover to click :)

Comment: thanks that works!